# Use arrays to perform 'VLookUp' type activity between workbooks

Tags: array, vba, excel

**Background**
I have the below UDF that opens a workbook (this workbook has extracted data from a queue within another app). I get the used range from this workbook and assign it to an array (`aExtractedRange`). One of the elements in this array has the workbook name that I need to open and get Application Name for each element in the array. I open the second workbook and assign the used range to a second array (`aOPRange`) so that search is more efficient

**Issue**
All of this works but as the first workbook can have 10K+ rows, it can take 30-40 seconds to perform this task. Is there anyway to make this faster? I have to work through few files a day so trying to see if I can improve the performance

**UDF**

```
Sub GetAppName()

    Set oWB = ThisWorkbook

    Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim oExtractedFilesFolder As Folder: Set oExtractedFilesFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(oWB.Worksheets("Info").Range("C3"))
    Dim oFile As File
    Dim aExtractedRange As Variant
    Dim iC As Long
    Dim sLastFile As String
    Dim oOPFile As File
    Dim aOPRange As Variant
    Dim sCurEFile As String
    Dim iKeyValueCol As Long, iTagsCol As Long, iAccountIDCol As Long, iSystemNameCol As Long
    Dim aAppName As Variant
    Dim iAppRow As Long
    Dim iLCol As Long

    ' Loop through all files in the specified folder
    For Each oFile In oExtractedFilesFolder.Files

        ' Check if current workbook is one of the expected workbooks
        If InStr(1, oFile.Name, "Queue Report", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

            ' Get used range from file
            aExtractedRange = GetUsedRangeData(oFile, True, iKeyValueCol, iTagsCol)

            ' Did we get the range
            If IsArray(aExtractedRange) Then

                ' Get app name for all items in the array
                For iC = LBound(aExtractedRange) To UBound(aExtractedRange)

                    ' Set current file name
                    If InStr(1, aExtractedRange(iC, iTagsCol), ";") > 0 Then
                        sCurEFile = Left(Replace(aExtractedRange(iC, iTagsCol), "_IN", "_OP"), InStr(1, aExtractedRange(iC, 5), ";") - 1)
                    Else
                        sCurEFile = Replace(aExtractedRange(iC, iTagsCol), "_IN", "_OP")
                    End If

                    ' If current file is the same as last file, skip this section as we already have the correct details in the array
                    If sLastFile <> sCurEFile Then

                        Set oOPFile = FindFile(sCurEFile, oFSO.GetFolder(oWB.Worksheets("Info").Range("C2")).Path)      ' Look for file in specified folder

                        aOPRange = GetUsedRangeData(oOPFile, False, iAccountIDCol, iSystemNameCol)      ' Get the used range from the file

                        sLastFile = sCurEFile

                    End If

                    ' Add element to app name array
                    If IsArray(aAppName) Then
                        ReDim Preserve aAppName(UBound(aAppName) + 1)
                    Else
                        ReDim aAppName(0)
                    End If

                    ' Find row with specific account number
                    iAppRow = 0
                    On Error Resume Next
                    iAppRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(aExtractedRange(iC, iKeyValueCol), Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(aOPRange, 0, iAccountIDCol), 0)
                    On Error GoTo 0

                    ' Set app name based on row number
                    If iAppRow > 0 Then
                        aAppName(UBound(aAppName)) = aOPRange(iAppRow, iSystemNameCol)
                    Else
                        aAppName(UBound(aAppName)) = ""
                    End If

                Next

            End If

        End If

    Next

    With oWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        ' Copy extracted data to sheet
        .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(aExtractedRange, 1), UBound(aExtractedRange, 2)).Value = aExtractedRange

        ' Get last column
        iLCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        ' Copy app name to sheet
        .Range(ColLetter(iLCol + 1) & "2").Resize(UBound(aAppName), 1).Value = aAppName
    End With

    ' Clear objects
    Set oExtractedFilesFolder = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

**P.S.**: UDF sits in a module and makes calls to some other UDF's. Happy to explain what they are if needed

**Edit**: Adding `GetUsedRangeData` as requested

```
Function GetUsedRangeData(ByVal oFile As File, ByVal bExtractFile As Boolean, ByRef iCol1 As Long, ByRef iCol2 As Long) As Variant

    Dim oExtractWB As Workbook
    Dim iLRow As Long
    Dim iLCol As Long
    Dim sColName As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set oExtractWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(oFile)

    If bExtractFile Then
        iCol1 = FindColumn(oExtractWB.Worksheets(1), "KeyValue")
        iCol2 = FindColumn(oExtractWB.Worksheets(1), "Tags")
    Else
        iCol1 = FindColumn(oExtractWB.Worksheets(1), "Account ID")
        iCol2 = FindColumn(oExtractWB.Worksheets(1), "System Name")
    End If

    If iCol1 >= 1 Or iCol2 >= 1 Then

        With oExtractWB.Worksheets(1)
            iLRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            iLCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            sColName = ColLetter(iLCol)

            GetUsedRangeData = .Range("A2:" & sColName & iLRow)

        End With

    End If

    oExtractWB.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set oExtractWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Try putting `aExtractedRange(iC, iTagsCol)` in a variable and more such repeated evaluations. That could make a difference. And the `aAppName` does not need a ReDim inside the loop; before the loop once would be nicer.

Comment: [Cross-posted from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52932177/1188513)

Comment: Using a `Scripting,Dictionary` insead of `WorksheetFunction.Match` would give you roughly a 10x speed boost.   You should incluce the `GetUsedRangeData()` function in your post.

Comment: @TinMan: I was thinking about using `Dictionary` but then I would have to create a dictionary from the array that holds the data from the files.. seems like it would take longer to do that as I need the multi dimensional array to populate at the end.. or maybe I am wrong? Added `GetUsedRangeData` UDF to the post

Comment: @JoopEggen: I think I am putting it in a variable: `sCurEFile`. I just format the text while I add it to the variable to a expected format. I then use `sCurEFile` for any further reference to file name

Comment: It is more the small expressions like a cell reference, that take time and when repeated, make things slow. About the cell reference I found that out after processing a sheet in java, but VB might have the same problem.

Comment: @JoopEggen: Yup, When referencing cells in Excel, it triggers all types of calculations. That's why I copy the range into and array and work with the array

Comment: I'm I right in assuming that: There seems to be only 1 `"Queue Report"`,  The System Name for each KeyValue is then looked up in the file referenced in the Tag column.   The  `"Queue Report"`, data and System Names are then copied to the Macro workbook.

Comment: @TinMan: Essentially yes. The code I have up here is doing that. Only difference being, all columns are captured from `Queue Report` file to local sheet with the addition of `App Name` column which is added to the local sheet as well after the last used column. Over all though, I will have multiple `Queue Reports` files (code in my Excel has moved on a bit to cater for that). All I wanted to know if there are more efficient ways of doing what the code is doing here

Comment: @Zac  I refactored your code using Dictionaries:  [GetAppNameVersion2.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c6wJTuRLmEforx8EIE1AQo-mTKDFqA9F).  If the `App Name` column is empty then I probably have the key and value columns backwards.  Without having the actual files it is hard to determine the best approach.  Notice that I resized `aExtractedRange()` to add an extra column for the `App Name`; this will give you a small increase in performance ~1 sec.  Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @TinMan: Great minds and all of that :): I changed that in my code as well: so the code now adds `AppName` to `aExtractedRange` array. This way I don't need the second array. Hasn't made much of a performance enhancement but certainly is cleaner and more maintainable code. I'm gona try and open the file and use **`VLookUp`** or **`Index+Match`**.. see if that makes any difference

Comment: @Zac do multiple `Queue Reports` get their `App Names` from the same files?

Comment: @TinMan: No. So `Queue Reports` file has a column called `Tags`. This column holds the file name (amongst other text). I extract the file name from this `Tags` column and match it against the last file name. If it's the same, I use the existing array. If it's not the same, I then open the file in `Tags` column and assign the contents of this file to the array. So, in summary, a `Queue Report` file could have rows where app names are held in different files (i.e. Row 1-50 might be for one app in a file and row 51-80 could be for another app in a different file)

Comment: @Zac Is there a chance that `Queue Report A` and `Queue Report B` would both refer to `Tag File A`?

Comment: @TinMan: Yes. Different `Queue Reports` can point to the same `Tag file`

Comment: @TinMan: Unfortunately I don't have access to your file from work. I'll try it when I get home tonight and give you an update. Thanks for all your input

Comment: @Zac I posted my code.  Keep in mind that I just did a quick hack of your code to get a working sample.  I my also have my keys and values reversed.

Comment: @TinMan: Brilliant, Thanks. I'll give that a go

Comment: @TinMan: Apologies for the delay but I got pulled over to other work. So I tried using `Dictionary` and here are the results: Using the same file, when processing with my `original` code, it took: **3 mins and 27 secs**. When using `Dictionary` approach, it took: **3 mins and 12 secs**. `Dictionary` does seem to be quicker and as the actual files I use will have a lot more data in them, it makes sense to go with `Dictionary` approach. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Zac that seems like a long time.  A single dictionary using the `path\filename||KeyValue"` for the keys would probably be a bit faster.  Glad that I could help.